# Visual Studio shortcut-key Build.BuildSelection, which one is the selection?

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio 2005 and later has a default hotkey F7 which is called `Build.BuildSelection`, but I'm quite baffled, in a multi-project sln, **which project is the "selection"?** Of course it is not the one set as Start-up project, which tells which project to debug when you press F5.

[image: Visual Studio Build.BuildSelection]

-- I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selection is the project that is currently selected in Solution Explorer (if Solution Explorer is focused) or it is the project that contains the file which is currently open (and focused) in editor. This way you can build other projects from the solution, different from startup project.

Also, note that if you have set up dependencies between projects, it is possible that more than one project will be built.

Comment: What do you mean by "select"? Just click the project name node in Solution Explorer pane? No, I tried it, not the case. Then is there any visual indication in VS IDE which project is selected? If yes, please give a screen shot.

Comment: Thank you. Tried it and VS2010 behaves right this way -- quite implicit rule.